# How do you respond when someone knocks on the toilet door?

Tags: word-requests

If you were using the toilet and someone knocked on the door what would be the common response to indicate it was occupied?

I noticed some Japanese people knock back, but it is not always possible, so how do you answer verbally?

Comment: I see possibilities for ふさがっている or 空いていない, but dictionaries do not give usage examples in this particular context.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think the most common phrase is...

> [入]{はい}ってます。

^.^

Comment: And press the nose while speaking to obscure our identity.

Comment: I agree simple is best, but how would the 空いていない sound to the Japanese ears? Strange?

Comment: @macraf It would probably be understood, but yeah a bit strange... (トイレの個室の外側にいる人が、トイレの個室に入ろうとしている人に、「(そこ、)空いてますよ。」/「空いてませんよ。」と言うことはあると思います。)

Comment: How about answering 「使用中です」? Would it sound strange?

Comment: @macraf あ、それなら、おかしくないと思います。　(^_^)

Comment: Even 使ってます！ would work.

Answer (score -1):

Just make sound of water by using flush or pour it in a bucket. Or just knock on bucket or something like tht if you're door is far.. 
the person will understand that someone is inside..

Advantage?

It works for all languages , not only Japanese..

Minus voters?
Only minus vote it if you haven't done it in your whole life time...

Comment: If you flush, someone outside expects you are done...

Comment: But they know atlast tht some one is there..

Comment: +1: It is a good way to hide our identity especially for women but it does not answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

Just do louder cough voice..this voice is helpful of your existence.I see most of the people doing that voice..Hope this answer can solve your problem